# Issues With JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to create a search engine using the Giphy.API, but once I get to the third step and JSON.parse it gives me Unexpected token character at Json[0]. I think it is trying parse what I input and not the api data. Any help is appreciated.

/* 1. Grab the input*/

```
document.querySelector(".js-go").addEventListener('click',function(){
    var input = document.querySelector("input").value;
    pushToDOM(input);
    });
document.querySelector(".js-userinput").addEventListener('keyup',function(e){
    var input = document.querySelector("input").value;
    if(e.which=== 13) {
    pushToDOM(input);
        }
    });
```

/*2. Do the API Data*/

```
function pushToDOM(input){
    var search =  input ;
    console.log(search);
    var api= "http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?"
    var apikey= "&api_key=dc6zaTOxFJmzC"
    var query = "&q="+ search
    var url = api+apikey+query
    console.log(url);
```

// AJAX Request

```
    var GiphyAJAXCall = new XMLHttpRequest();
    GiphyAJAXCall.open( 'GET', url );
    GiphyAJAXCall.send();
    GiphyAJAXCall.addEventListener('load',function(e){

    var data = e.target.response;
    pushToDOM(data);
})};
```

/*3. Show the gifs*/

```
    function pushToDOM(input){

        var response = JSON.parse(input)
        //console.log(response)}
        var imgURLs = response.data;
        var container = document.querySelector(".js-container")
        container.innerHTML = data};
        imgURLs.forEach(function(image){

        var src = image.images.fixed_height.url;
        console.log(src)

        container.innerHTML +=  "<img src=\"" + src + "\" class= \"container-image\">";
        })}
```

Comment: Is the response already json though? What do you see from `e.target.response;` is it a string?

Comment: Here is part of what i get from e.target.response {"data":[{"type":"gif","id":"3o6gaYp40rWbo2rZVS","slug":"birthday-dog-happy-birthday-no1curr-3o6gaYp40rWbo2rZVS","url":"http:\/\/giphy.com\/gifs\/birthday-dog-happy-birthday-no1curr-3o6gaYp40rWbo2rZVS","bitly_gif_url":"http:\/\/gph.is\/20Qvwgm",

Answer (score 0):

The response from the giphy api in plain text comes back with a bunch of white space and line breaks either side of the JSON. You'll need to remove the initial whitespace and linebreaks, and then use `.trim()` to clear out this whitespace from the end of response before you can parse it. try something like:

```
var data = e.target.response.replace(/^\s+\{/, '{').trim();
pushToDOM(data);
```

Regex explained:

- `^` denotes beginning of string
- `\s` denotes any whitespace character `[\r\n\t\f\v ]`
- `+` qualifier matches between one and unlimited times
- `\{` denotes the literal character `{`

Replace the match with just the literal character `{` because we've captured it in our regex, then use javascript native `.trim()` method to strip trailing whitespace

If it makes you feel better, the problem was on the API side, not in your code :)

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/kxhgj1zf/2)**